# Why has this question been closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

Once this question was considered on-topic here: [If I have the Comixology app, do I need the publisher ones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12845/if-i-have-the-comixology-app-do-i-need-the-publisher-ones)

Today, I asked a similar question: [How does unlimited subscription of Marvel Comics work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/how-does-unlimited-subscription-of-marvel-comics-work) which is closed as off-topic. Why?

Answer (score 11):

Those questions don't have anything to do with Science Fiction or Fantasy. It has to do with the distribution of (potentially) SciFi/Fantasy works.

Similarily a question like "How do I buy a comic book from a grocery store" would be closed as off topic. Just because you mentioned a comic book doesn't mean it is on topic. The question is about the logistics of purchasing a magazine. It has nothing to do with this genre.

Comment: Yes, but then why was the first question also not off-topic?

Comment: @MarkBeadles Because no one noticed? I agree both should be closed.

Comment: @Beofett Ha, fair enough.

Comment: See also [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/275243) for a related precedent from another stack.  As a side note, in my experience it's often considered "OK" to put this sort of information into [tag:suggested-order] answers (in addition to answering the main question), especially when the work is otherwise difficult to find.

Answer (score 4):

To me these questions are no different than asking "**How do I buy a ticket to see Prometheus at my local cinema?**", or "**How do I stream Battlestar Galactica on Netflix**"?

Are they *about* science fiction? Only peripherally. They're not about the content, or the creation, or the fandom culture, or speculation. They're about buying and downloading -- the content happens to be Sci-Fi in this case. But the same answers would apply if I asked about downloading Archie comics or Downton Abbey episodes. Those are fine things - but they're not Sci-Fi/Fantasy.

Answer (score -4):

It's clearly on-topic (although it doesn't seem like a *good* question; as a comment says, it seems very likely that the terms of use would answer it).

The FAQ states that questions about:

> Behind-the-scenes and fandom information

are on-topic.  These questions are those. However, these questions are rare, and so can easily get closed as off-topic simply because they don't fit the dull trivia-contest or wild-speculation question format questions that users are expecting.

The best way to figure out whether something is off-topic (other than referring to the FAQ and meta questions) is to ask "is this something that requires the expertise likely to be found on this site?" - i.e. does it require expertise in science fiction/fantasy.  Here, given that the vast majority of the material sold through these applications consists of on-topic material here (i.e. it's scifi/fantasy), it seems clear that the users here are likely to have the expertise to answer the question.

Related to this is another question: would the users of this site be expected to find this question interesting and useful: the answer is again clearly "yes" - the users are likely to be consuming science-fiction/fantasy with these applications, and knowing more about how to best do that would be both useful and interesting.

These questions aren't any different in nature than a question asking what you need to know to try and find a rare translation of a scifi/fantasy book (shopping questions in general are off-topic, of course).  WRT to shopping questions, the general guideline is:

> Thus, when it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy.

That's exactly this question: asking what needs to be learnt (how the different models work for purchasing this scifi/fantasy content), not asking what needs to be bought.

Comment: I disagree that it's "clearly" on topic, unless you are just using "clearly" for rhetorical effect. This is a grey area, as evidenced by this very discussion. I don't think that "what you need to learn to tell what you should buy" really should extend to software and licensing questions -- I mean, where would that end?

Comment: I see this as no different than "I use my television to watch sci-fi, therefore it is on-topic to ask what episodes and seasons of each show I will gain access to by subscribing to various cable television packages."  The question isn't *about* sci-fi topics.  It is about *tools* used that happen to be associated with scifi material. That's not "behind-the-scenes and fandom information". "Behind-the-scenes" is more "how much more did Bret Spiner get paid for *First Contact* than Marina Sirtris?"

Comment: [When we wrote the FAQ](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/350/366), the intent of the line you quote as clearly making this question on-topic was [for "lifestyle" SFF questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/359/366): how do I prepare for a convention, why are people bullying me for liking Star Wars, etc. And even *then* it's still controversial as to whether it's on-topic here. Not sure how you came to construe that to mean questions about app recommendations were on-topic.

Answer (score -6):

I agree that it's on topic.
I think, due to the factors that are asked, extant users of the license in question are far better able to answer - such behaviors as mentioned are seldom covered in the Terms of Use for many such services, and when they are, often not in plain English.

Comment: I think it's a good question, and answerable, perhaps even by some people who use this site. But in my opinion it's really not a Sci-Fi/Fantasy question.